# Solution of equation in $k$, $\sin k$ and $\cos k$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, transcendental-numbers

Some [physical problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465109/particle-in-a-box-plus-step-ground-state) reduces to some equation that looks pretty transcendental:

$$
k \sin\mathopen{}\left(\sqrt{k^2+2\delta}\,\pi/2\right)\mathclose{}\cos(k\pi/2) + \sqrt{k^2+2\delta}\cos\mathopen{}\left(\sqrt{k^2+2\delta}\,\pi/2\right)\mathclose{}\sin(k\pi/2) =0.
$$

with $\delta\ < k \in \Bbb R^+$.

For $\delta=0$ the solutions are $k\in\Bbb N$. What could one do for $\delta\ne 0$?

Comment: If $\delta << k$, you can try Taylor-expanding the sines and cosines (as well as the square roots).  Grouping the terms order-by-order of $\delta$ will give your a series expansion for the solution $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\delta \leq 0$, the equation LHS gives complex values when $|k| < \sqrt{-2\delta}$ and the only solution is $|k| = \sqrt{-2\delta}$.

The matter is much more interesting for $\delta > 0$. There is a set of discrete values of $\delta$ for which the equation can be solved exactly for $k$. Namely, if $\delta = 2n+2$ with $n \in \Bbb N$ then $k=n$ solves the equation, because then $\sqrt{k^2+2\delta} = k+2$ so the LHS becomes
$$
k \sin \left(k \frac{\pi}2 + \pi \right) \cos  \left(k \frac{\pi}2 \right)
+  (k+2) \cos \left(k \frac{\pi}2 + \pi \right) \sin  \left(k \frac{\pi}2 \right) \\=
(-k-(k+2)) \sin \left(k \frac{\pi}2 \right) \cos \left(k \frac{\pi}2 \right) =
-(2k+2) \sin k\pi = 0
$$
For $\delta = 2n+2+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ small,we can do perturbation expansion, and the results are intriguing.  When $n$ is even, it seems the function is zero at 
$$k = \frac{n-3}{2n+2} \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2)$$

But when $n$ is odd, it seems the solution value of $k$ moves away from its integer value much more rapidly as $\delta$ moves from its even integer value.  The behavior is
$$
k = \frac{n+2}{2} \sqrt{\epsilon} + \frac{n}{4n+4} \epsilon + O(\epsilon^{3/2})$$

and this covers the solutions on both sides of the except that there are no solutions for $0 < \delta < 4$.

This lack of solutions must have some physical meaning; I suspect that for these values of $\delta$ the energy is too small and the solution to the left of the boundary is a decaying exponential rather than a sine wave.

Comment: "and this covers the solutions on both sides of the except that there are no solutions for 0<<4. " Numerically this is not confirmed. $\delta=0.1$ gives about $0.947$ for $k$, which makes sense, as well.

Comment: Physically <0 is completely equivalent to >0, though the problem was formulated bearing in mind that both  and  are in ℝ+, that was what was intended in my clumsy formulation <∈ℝ+. Integer k are the solutions for =0, since  should be smaller  the most interesting values are <<1. The discrete spectrum otherwise just reflects the quantization. To put in in another way, its exactly the $\varepsilon$ dependence which is of interest.

Comment: Due to the symmetry of the problem (symmetric with respect to reflection at $x=\pi/4$ in the arguments of the trigonometric functions) only one in $n$ even or odd should produce valid solutions. The other ones should be like "artefacts" from the calculation.